# Haskell Reader monad and argument passing

Tags: haskell

I was following this tutorial https://blog.ssanj.net/posts/2014-09-23-A-Simple-Reader-Monad-Example.html

It has tree functions that is embarrassing to me

```
tom :: Reader String String
tom = do
  env <- ask
  return (env ++ " This is tom.")

jerry :: Reader String String
jerry = do
  env <- ask
  return (env ++ " This is Jerry.")

tomAndJerry :: Reader String String
tomAndJerry = do
   t <- tom
   j <- jerry
   return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)

runJerryRun :: String
runJerryRun  = (runReader tomAndJerry) "Who is this?"
```

These functions receive no arguments but still they access the reader monad, what magic is happening here? What is the intuition behind this?

I reader monad a kind of global?

Comment: `Reader r a` is isomorphic to `r -> a`. So your assertion that "these functions receive no arguments" is technically correct, but not really representative of the truth: all of the `Reader` actions shown here receive a `String` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the first two functions returns its own instance of a Reader monad. Then, you can compose them together (in the third function).

For the sake of the argument, let's replace `Reader` with `IO` and do something similar, with none of these functions receiving any argument:

```hs
getIntFromFile :: IO Int
getIntFromFile = do
    x <- readFile "myfile.txt"
    pure $ read x :: Int

getIntFromStdin :: IO Int
getIntFromStdin = do
    x <- getLine
    pure $ read x :: Int
```

As you can see, both use the `IO` monad but they don't share anything in common. However, since they both use the `IO` monad, you can (and that's the beauty of it) compose them together as follows:

```hs
-- | the equivalent of your `tomAndJerry` function
main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- getIntFromFile
    y <- getIntFromStdin
    print $ x + y
```

This is exactly the same logic at play with the example from the tutorial, except with `Reader` instead of `IO`.

Comment: Oh, so the return in that functions are in fact instantiating a Reader monad, I didn't realized that I was expecting to receive something as output a return a transformed sort of thing as output, now it makes sense to me Thanks

Comment: In IO is pretty clear from where the input is coming, file and stdin, but what in Reader? It has a magical object siting in memory from where it can bind and lookup things?

Comment: @geckos the input is whatever is provided to `runReader someValueInTheReaderMonad`. `x <- someReader` in the context of the Reader Monad means that x is the output of the function (`someReader` being basically a wrapper around an ordinary function) when given whatever input you later specify. Using the Reader monad just allows you to run a bunch of functions on the same input and do whatever calculations you want with them, while only having to provide that input once.

Answer (score 3):

I think one important misunderstanding was addressed by Daniel Wagner in a comment. The `Reader` is (well, wraps) a function, so it does take arguments. In light of this, I guess your final question

> I reader monad a kind of global?

has an answer: yes, in the sense that the reader monad gives you a way to pass an immutable state/environment through chained computations; so it kind of reads the same value everytime it's invoked (via `ask`) along the chain.

Which in the case of your code means that the two `ask`s (or, equivalently, `tom` and  `jerry`) both read the same environment, represented by the string `"Who is this?"`.

Imho, this becomes a bit clearer by desugaring the `do`s:

```hs
tom :: Reader String String
tom = ask >>= \env -> return (env ++ " This is Tom.")

jerry :: Reader String String
jerry = ask >>= \env -> return (env ++ " This is Jerry.")

tomAndJerry :: Reader String String
tomAndJerry = tom >>= \t -> jerry >>= \j -> return (t ++ "\n" ++ j)
```

Here `>>=` expects a function that returns a monad, but you don't have it, you have the "ordinary" function (e.g. `\env -> env ++ " This is Tom."`), so you have to use `return` to wrap the result back into the monad. Then instead of using `>>=` and `return . f`, why don't we use `fmap f`, since we only have to apply a function inside the monad?

Which means that we can go further and simplify by using `Functor` for `tom` and `jerry` and `Applicative` for `tomAndJerry`.

```hs
tom :: Reader String String
tom = fmap (++ " This is Tom.") ask

jerry :: Reader String String
jerry = fmap (++ " This is Jerry.") ask

tomAndJerry :: Reader String String
tomAndJerry = (\t j -> t ++ "\n" ++ j) <$> tom <*> jerry
```

Both `tom` and `jerry` are `ask`ing for the environment, and each of them applies a function to it. Then `tomAndJerry` is just a way of composing them via a binary function, as pointed out in the accepted answer.

By the way, the language server tells me of `asks`, which allows to write

```hs
tom :: Reader String String
tom = asks (++ " This is Tom.")
```